# TS2307 error when including external modules to Typescript file

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I installed a module via npm, and am trying to access it inside my typescript file.

```
npm install marker-animate-unobtrusive --save

import SlidingMarker = require('marker-animate-unobtrusive');
```

This results in

```
//Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'marker-animate-unobtrusive'
```

Search for this issue brings upchanging the compiler options, others mention creating a d.ts file for Type Script to recognize the module, but I never got a clear answer anywhere. I tried these methods, but with little success so far.
I am using Angular 2 and Ionic 2 for this, if that information helps.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the SlidingMarker npm module doesn't yet have a type definition.

1) Create generic definition in typings/marker-animate-unobtrusive.d.ts:

```
declare module 'marker-animate-unobtrusive' {
  const x: any;
  export = x;
}
```

2) Add this file to list of definitions in typings/main.d.ts (or typings/index.d.ts if you are using the newer typings):

```
/// <reference path="marker-animate-unobtrusive.d.ts"></reference>
```

3) Next, update your import statement:

```
import * as SlidingMarker from 'marker-animate-unobtrusive';
```

Volia! Note, you may need to change any variables cast as "SlidingMarker" to "any" to avoid other TypeScript errors.